# Could not initialize proxy - no Session, inside Spring interceptor

Tags: java, spring, session, lazy-evaluation, interceptor

I have an interceptor in my configuration, and I want to forbid access to other users' resources. Inside the WebMvcConfig (implements WebMvcConfigurer), I have:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new FolderInterceptor(userService, folderService))
            .addPathPatterns(Mapping.FOLDER_MAPPING + "/{id}",
                    Mapping.UPDATE_FOLDER_MAPPING + "/{id}",
                    Mapping.DELETE_FOLDER_MAPPING + "/{id}",
                    Mapping.DOWNLOAD_FOLDER_MAPPING + "/{id}");

}
```

In my FolderInterceptor, I have a preHandle method getting the accessed folder and checking its owner:

```
Map pathVariables = (Map) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
Long id = Long.valueOf((String) pathVariables.get("id"));

User user = userService.getLoggedAccount();

if (folderService.existsById(id)) {
    Folder folder = folderService.findById(id);

    if (folder.getOwner().getId().equals(user.getId())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        response.sendError(403, "Unauthorized");
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    response.sendError(404, "Folder does not exist");
    return false;
}
```

If I print the folder object, I have the same error on that line.

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy.
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no tx and hence no session/entitymanager and thus this exception. The code you have in your interceptor belongs in a single transactional service method. Instead of calling all the different methods in your interceptor.

Comment: I should add that a friend of mine showed me his project that works perfectly and I took his exact same interceptor method, and only renamed the object he had with mine (Folder).

Comment: The fact that it works on another project doesn't mean it automatically works. You have a different setup (probably no open session/entitymanager in view) which he had. He had no no lazy loading, you probably have. Regardless of all that, it should be, ideally, in a single transactional method, which will solve the issue. Or modify your object model to not use lazy loading (but that might have an impact of the other parts of your application).

Comment: I have no lazy loading in my model, I made sure of that. And apart from the version of the different dependencies, our two projects are very similar in structure. If it's not because of the version, I don't see what it is.

Comment: @ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="owner")
private User owner;

This is how I have my owner in my entity

Comment: Let me guess in your `FolderServive` you are doiing `getById` instead of `findById`...

Comment: I use getOne. And indeed, I don't get the difference between findById, getOne and findOne

Comment: Okay, I found that getOne is lazy loaded...

Comment: get never hits the database and always returns directly with a LAZY proxy. So even if the actual entity doesn't exists it will give you a `Folder` and lead to issues as soon as you try to call getters/setters on it, which then will go to the database. The find will query the database and return an actual `Folder` or `null` when not found. Hence you are using lazy loading...

Comment: Okay, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the getOne method to retrieve my folder by id in my service. Now using folderRepository.findById(id) and this works for now:

```
public Folder findById(Long id) {

    Optional<Folder> folder = folderRepository.findById(id);

    if (!folder.isPresent())
        return null;

    return folder.get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving a `Folder` entity most likely without any dependency fetching under one transaction here:

```
Folder folder = folderService.findById(id);
```

Then when you try to access the `folder.getOwner()`, the Owner dependency was not fetched and the persistence provider tries to lazy-load it from the database:

```
if (folder.getOwner().getId().equals(user.getId())) {
    return true;
}
```

The problem is that `folder` is out of transaction scope and a detached entity.

I would suggest fetching the `Owner`  inside the `folderService.findById(id)` method or put the query and the conditional under same transactional method.